# Why is there destructive interference in an atom between protons and electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, interference, orbitals, binding-energy

> "In energy wave theory, Planck’s relation describes the energy of a transverse wave, emitted or absorbed as an electron transitions energy levels in an atom. When an electron is contained within an atom, destructive wave interference between protons in the nucleus and the electron causes destructive waves, resulting in binding energy. This binding energy becomes the energy of a photon that is released when an electron is captured or moves states in an atom. The electron’s vibration causes a transverse wave and the photon’s energy is based on the frequency of this vibration."

This is the exact paragraph from the internet.
Could anyone help in decoding it?

Comment: Can you add a link to the source, along with a description of it in case the link breaks? (For what it's worth, the paragraph is not very clear to me, either. There are much better descriptions of emission of light from atomic transitions, such as Sections 4.3 and 4.4 of David Tong's lectures on quantum mechanics http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/quantum.html)

Comment: It sounds like a non mainstream interpretation of what for  mainstream physics are bound states in a quantum mechanical solution. The only waves are connected with probability , in mainstream quantum mechanics, https://energywavetheory.com/introduction/

Comment: @Andrew https://energywavetheory.com/equations/ehf/ - link

Comment: Well, it looks like this "energy wave theory" is not based on any peer reviewed publications, looking at the supporting documents. "Energy wave theory" is certainly not mainstream physics. My unsolicited advice is that you should be very skeptical of any claims you find on that site. If you are genuinely interested in learning physics, I would strongly suggest not spending time on this website at all and instead find a mainstream source at your level to study.

Comment: @Andrew , seems like I should be more careful with the info I read on the internet any sites that u could recommend which are more theoretical and don't involve complex mathematics as being a sophomore in school ...